# Not able to update list field properties using sharepoint powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

How do I use PowerShell to update list field properties? When I try the following:

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://vikas:26112/"

$web= $site.OpenWeb()   

$spList = $web.GetList("/Lists/Support Links") 
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text
$spList.Fields.Add("FirstName",$spFieldType,$false)
$spList.Fields[“FirstName”].Description = “My FirstName Field”
$spList.Fields[“FirstName”].Required=$true
$spList.Fields["FirstName"].EnforceUniqueValues=$true
$spList.update()

$web.Dispose()
```

After executing this `FirstName` field is added to list but properties of this field remains   unchanged:

```
Description =""  
Required=false  
EnforceUniqueValues=false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are not updating the field and that indexer is returning different instances each time you use it. You must store the instance of the field in some variable, then change it, then update it.

Change your code like this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://vikas:26112/"
$web= $site.OpenWeb()   
$spList = $web.GetList("/Lists/Support Links") 
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text
$spList.Fields.Add("FirstName",$spFieldType,$false)
$field = $spList.Fields[“FirstName”]
$field.Description = “My FirstName Field”
$field.Required=$true
$field.EnforceUniqueValues=$true
$field.update()

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: thanks jumbo for your quick response...
By the way i got this mistake myself